# Using a variable within an ActionScript 3 embed statement

Tags: image, variables, actionscript, adobe, embedding

I have a set of images within a directory called assets/images/pieces named 1.png, 2.png 3.png etc. My question is, how can I load these images using a random variable within Action Script 3?

Could I do what I have entered below?

```
/** Typical Embed Statement **/
[Embed(source="image/path/here")]

/** Modified **/
var path_name = "image/path/here/";
[Embed(source=path_name)]
```

Answer (score 0):

My understaning is that you can't do it because the Embed Tag executes at compile time so path_name doesn't have a values assigned to it yet and you will get an error:

```
"Unable to resolve path_name"
```

To handle the embed at run-time you will probably have to use URLLoader. But keep in mind it is asynchronous and you will have to wait for a COMPLETE event before being able to use the image.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html